# STR_TO_DATE parsing in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to parse "06/01/2010 15:00:00 08:00".

The problem is the last offset hour, mysql `str_to_date` can't parse it, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [CONVERT_TZ function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), but you didn't specify what timezone you want to convert the datetime to:

```
CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('06/01/2010 15:00:00 08:00', 20), '%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
           CONCAT('+', RIGHT('06/01/2010 15:00:00 08:00', 6)),
           ?)
```

You need to replace the `?` with the appropriate timezone info.