# Inserting a date in RFC2822 format - no timezone specifier?

Tags: mysql, time, timezone, convert-tz, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a string in **RFC2822** format and I would like to insert the appropiate timestamp in UTC time.

Until now I've come up with

```
DATE_FORMAT(?, "%a, %d %b %Y %T -0700")
```

but the problem is the TZ offset `-0700`, there seems to be no format specifier for it.

How to properly insert such a timestamp into the database?

I would like to avoid processing on the application side.

**Update**

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING('Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0200',1,25), '%a, %d %b %Y %T'),CONCAT(SUBSTRING('Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0200',27,3), ':', SUBSTRING('Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0200',30,2)),'+00:00') AS conv;
```

**How to do it "cleanly" by using a variable instead of repeating the string `Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0200`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STR\_TO\_DATE parsing in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039700/str-to-date-parsing-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @a:='Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0200';
SELECT
  CONVERT_TZ(
    STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(@a,1,25), '%a, %d %b %Y %T'),
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@a,27,3), ':', SUBSTRING(@a,30,2)),
    '+00:00'
  )
AS conv;
```

That's what I call an answer.